# My Seagate hard disk shows that's is RAW and also show that is 0 bytes

Tags: ntfs, formatting

My Seagate hard disk shows that's is RAW and also show that is 0 bytes and in diskpart it shows that it is healthy, when trying to format to NTFS using diskpart it is stuck on 0%.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider buying a new one... If formatting doesn't work, it's very likely broken.

Comment: 1. Delete all partitions. 2. "Save all" or "Commit" (most tools do not complete a step without confirmation). 3. Create one partition. 4. Commit. 5. Format that partition.